# 100th derivative of $ g(x) = (x^3 -4x + 7)^{30} $. Where is the pattern?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule, pattern-recognition

I was reviewing come Calc 1 problems, and came across one that asks us to explain what the 100th derivative of

$$ g(x) = (x^3 -4x + 7)^{30} $$

would be.
I computed the first three derivatives:

$$ g'(x) = 30(x^3-4x+7)^{29}(3x^2-4) $$
$$ g''(x) = 30*29(x^3-4x+7)^{28}(3x^2-4)+(6x)(30(x^3-4x+7)^{29})$$

Very quickly we can see we will have to continue doing chain rules and product rules every time we take a derivative. I also took the 3rd derivative, but the termas quickly expand and I do not see a pattern such that I can figure out what is supposed to happen at 100th derivative (especially because the chain rule and product rules really add terms). I calculated the answer online, and it is supposed to be zero, but this is not evident to me at all. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is the degree of $g$? How much is the degree reduced when taking the derivative? Write $g(x)=x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+ \cdots $ and then differentiate $n+1$-times - or more.

Comment: The leading term of the polynomial is $(x^3 - 4x + 7)^{30} \sim (x^3)^{30} = x^{90}$. Hence the $100$-th derivative is zero.

Comment: Thank you for your input guys, feel free to add it as a solution so I may marked this question as solved.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The highest power of $x$ in $g$ is $(x^3)^{30}=x^{90}$ which vanishes on the $91$st derivative. So,
$$g^{(100)}(x)=0$$

Answer (score 3):

If $g(x)=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots +a_0$, then differentiating it $(n+1)$-times gives zero. Now we have
$$
g(x)=(x^3-4x+7)^{30}=x^{90} - 120x^{88} + 210x^{87} + \cdots + 22539340290692258087863249,
$$
to be precise (we do not need the exact coefficients, of course).